# iTunes doesn't see my iDevices - OS X

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I have a desktop (Mac Pro 5,1) and a laptop computer (MBA 4,2). Both are running 10.10.1. I have an iPad3 and an iPhone 6.

Maybe there is a new method in iTunes, but I cannot see either device on either computer.

Anyone know what's going on? Let me know if I should provide more info. All my software is up to date.

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to "see" them?

Comment: To update software, add music, books, etc

Comment: Could you try General → Settings → iTunes Wifi Sync to check if works?

Comment: Thanks. To use Wi-Fi syncing, I must be able to access my devices using iTunes first..

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions on Apple Support Communities. Apple's solution is first. That didn't work for me. The second method worked for me on two computers and three devices. And no side effects so far, i.e. Time Machine is fine. It is not Apple's recommended method.

1. Apple solution:

1.1 Terminal:
defaults delete com.apple.SyncServer SyncServicesResetWorldRunOnce

1.2 Reboot your computer.

1.3 Unplug and reconnect your device(s)

See [this link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203202) for the article

2. Hatchet solution

2.1. Go to ~/Library/ApplicationSupport

2.2. Find the folder SyncServices

2.3. Delete it.

2.4. Reboot your computer

2.5. Unplug and reconnect your iOS device(s).

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to only be a temporary fix. I have seen the problem recur now.